# How can the number of possible audio files be quantified?

Tags: audio

If you have RGB images of m px × n px, then you can have 256^(m*n*3) images. The reason is that each pixel is independent of each other pixel (m*n), and for each pixel you have 3 color channels. Except for non-standard formats, each color channel has 256 possible values. Hence 256^(3*m*n) possible images in total.

Can you make a similar statement for audio files? Could you explain it in a similar way?

Answer (score 0):

PCM data used for most audio recordings uses:

- Number of samples per second, for example 44100, 48000, 96000
- Number of bits per sample, for example 8, 16, or 24
- Number of channels - 1 (mono), 2 (stereo), more for various surround formats

So a second of audio has 'sample rate * 2 ^ bps * channels' possible values.